# How to create nodes using node_save?

Tags: 7, nodes, migrations

I'm trying to migrate my current html site into Drupal. I have over 80,000 pages I have to migrate so I thought instead of sitting in front of a computer for 50 years I would create a module. I was able to create a script that extracts the html from each directory and now I got to a road block where I need to create a node. I'm trying to create a new node using `node_save()`, but when node_save is executed, I get a `PDOException` error with everything I try. I'm passing in `$node`, which is an array which is then casted into an object.

> PDOException: in field_sql_storage_field_storage_write() (line 424 of /srv/www/htdocs/modules/field/modules/field_sql_storage/field_sql_storage.module).

This is how we are currently creating the node, but it produces an error:

```
$node= array(
    'uid' => $user->uid,
    'name' => $user->name,
    'type' => 'page',
    'language' => LANGUAGE_NONE,
    'title' => $html['title'],
    'status' => 1,
    'promote' => 0,
    'sticky' => 0,
    'created' => (int)REQUEST_TIME,
    'revision' => 0,
    'comment' => '1',
    'menu' => array(
        'enabled' => 0,
        'mlid' => 0,
        'module' => 'menu',
        'hidden' => 0,
        'has_children' => 0,
        'customized' => 0,
        'options' => array(),
        'expanded' => 0,
        'parent_depth_limit' => 8,
        'link_title' => '',
        'description' => '',
        'parent' => 'main-menu:0',
        'weight' => '0',
        'plid' => '0',
        'menu_name' => 'main-menu',
    ),
    'path' => array(
        'alias' => '',
        'pid' => null,
        'source' => null,
        'language' => LANGUAGE_NONE,
        'pathauto' => 1,
    ),
    'nid' => null,
    'vid' => null,
    'changed' => '',
    'additional_settings__active_tab' => 'edit-menu',
    'log' => '',
    'date' => '',
    'submit' => 'Save',
    'preview' => 'Preview',
    'private' => 0,
    'op' => 'Save',
    'body' => array(LANGUAGE_NONE => array(
        array(
            'value' => $html['html'],
            'summary' => $link,
            'format' => 'full_html',
        ),
    )),
        'validated' => true,
);

node_save((object)$node);

// Small hack to link revisions to our test user.
db_update('node_revision')
    ->fields(array('uid' => $node->uid))
    ->condition('vid', $node->vid)
    ->execute();
```

Answer (score 6):

Instead of casting an array into a `stdClass` object, you could try creating a new `stdClass()` object and then using [node_object_prepare](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_object_prepare/7.x)() to prepare the object for creating a new node and then finally manually changing the values of uid, name, title, language, body, etc. Also, be sure to use [node_submit](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_submit/7.x)() before saving the new node to the database.

Example: http://drupal.org/node/1173136

Answer (score 6):

I think that you should read [How to programmatically create nodes, comments and taxonomies in Drupal 7](http://timonweb.com/how-programmatically-create-nodes-comments-and-taxonomies-drupal-7).

```
$node = new stdClass(); // We create a new node object
$node->type = "page"; // Or any other content type you want
$node->title = "Your title goes jere";
$node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE; // Or any language code if Locale module is enabled. More on this below *
$node->path = array('alias' => 'your node path'); // Setting a node path
node_object_prepare($node); // Set some default values.
$node->uid = 1; // Or any id you wish

// Let's add standard body field
$node->body[$node->language][0]['value'] = 'This is a body text';
$node->body[$node->language][0]['summary'] = 'Here goes a summary';
$node->body[$node->language][0]['format'] = 'filtered_html'; // If field has a format, you need to define it. Here we define a default filtered_html format for a body field

$node = node_submit($node); // Prepare node for a submit
node_save($node); // After this call we'll get a nid
```

Comment: why the downvote?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is, that you are trying to create a new node with nid=null and vid=null, which is screwing up the node table as you are trying to insert new records with index number 0 - which is creating a duplicate entries problem and confusing drupal core. By the way - drupal core is vulnerable for such actions as node_save will not see the problem and try to insert that record into the db - which is causing a sql error - and throwing out a PDO exception